# Passing customizable options to a GraalVM image execution in a distroless environment

Tags: java, docker, graalvm, distroless

For context, I'm building a java application compiled to GraalVM native image running on a [distroless](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) docker image in Kubernetes.

I've been trying to do something rather simple and hit a wall: I'd like to set custom heap size limits per environment via `-XmxNNN`. To do that, the options with which I'd like to run the application would be held in an environment variable. The problem arises due to the usage of a distroless image - which doesn't have bash and so `ENTRYPOINT /application $OPTIONS` doesn't work.

Is there an environment variable GraalVM supports on its own, or any other way of setting this?

I dont want to:

- hardcode the values in the Docker image
- hardcode the values by [predefining them during native-image build](https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/MemoryManagement/#java-heap-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `busybox` to get a shell inside a distroless container:

```
FROM gcr.io/distroless/base

...

COPY --from=amd64/busybox:1.31.1 /bin/busybox /busybox/busybox
RUN ["/busybox/busybox", "--install", "/bin"]

CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "java -version"]
```

You can find an example to this kind of `Dockerfile` [here](https://github.com/qaware/distroless-graalvm-ce/blob/master/20.1.0-java11/Dockerfile).

But I don't think this busybox shell is necessary needed.

Altough `ENTRYPOINT /application $OPTIONS` does not work, this will work `ENTRYPOINT ["myapp", "arguments"]`

> Note that distroless images by default do not contain a shell. That means the Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT command, when defined, must be specified in vector form, to avoid the container runtime prefixing with a shell.

source: [github](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless#entrypoints)

Comment: yes, with the vector form it indeed starts, but then the variables can't be dynamically defined without editing the Dockerfile, right?

Comment: the busybox approach works great though, with only minimal increase to the image size - thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it will work, but you could try setting the environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to the desired value:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-XmxNNN
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html):

> This environment variable allows you to specify the initialization of
> tools, specifically the launching of native or Java programming language
> agents using the -agentlib or -javaagent options. In the following example
> the environment variable is set so that the HPROF profiler is launched when > the application is started:
>
> `$ export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-agentlib:hprof"`
>
> This variable can also be used to augment the command line with other
> options for diagnostic purposes. For example, you can supply the
> `-XX:OnError` option to specify a script or command to be executed when a
> fatal error occurs.

The [GraalVM documentation](https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/Agent/#injecting-the-agent-via-the-process-environment) itself provides an example of use as well, although in a different context.

Comment: From my testing - I'm afraid this doesn't work. The example provided in GraalVM documentation is for launching classic Java applications with native-image-agent, where this environment variable is respected by java. It doesn't seem to be respected during native-image execution. I was looking for an equivalent that would.

Comment: I am very sorry to hear that it doesn't work with Graalvm @Inqy. Another think you could try will be to [tune in some way](https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/MemoryManagement/) the _percentage_ of physical memory used. Every garbage collector provides you the necessary environment variables for that purpose: you could then rely on your physical resources and the Kubernetes resource limits to indirectly control the amount of memory used by the VM. The only drawback is that you will need to hardcode some values, although relative ones, in the `Dockerfile`.